# How to mark a certain S3 file as Make Public

Tags: java, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

How to mark a certain S3 file as Make Public via the webservices API.

Comment: Are you talking about REST web-services or AWS SDKs (java,php)

Answer (score 37):

Use method `setCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead)` to change Access control rights. Read java doc for details [here](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/PutObjectRequest.html#setCannedAcl%28com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.CannedAccessControlList%29)

**Sample Code:**

```
BasicAWSCredentials basicAWSCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(ACCESS_KEY,SECRET_KEY);   
AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client(basicAWSCredentials);

PutObjectRequest putObj = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, objectKey, fileToUpload);

// making the object Public
putObj.setCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);

s3.putObject(putObj);
```