# How can I access images in my aws s3 bucket in a django html tag?

Tags: html, django, amazon-s3, django-storage

I'm not very knowledgeable about this topic so I'm going to keep this simple.

I set up AWS S3 Storage with Django. When I upload images to one of my models, the image shows up in the appropriate bucket (good).

I'm not sure how to access an object inside my storage already. I have an image, say 'apple.jpg' and I want to display it on the website. How do I get this to show? My research says it has to do with AWS_Location but I'm really not sure.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show us your related models and views

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Amazon S3 Access image by url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6975693/amazon-s3-access-image-by-url)